# Email newsletter overflow

Tags: php, email

I am building a subscription option to my site's news feed that I believe is called a newsletter ( not an englishman ) and what I have done is allow users to subscribe which would lead to their email being inserted into a table. After which every time we post news they are automatically sent to the subscribed user's email. What I'm worried about is if the site comes to a point where we have like a really large amount of subscribers. Isn't sending out that many emails at once going to cause an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually shared hosting providers have restrictions on how many emails you could send per hour and per day - I have dealt with 100 per hour. After getting over it the settings on the server automatically change to disable your mail() function.

If you have your own dedicated server, this might not be the issue, but there comes another problem - your server IP address might become blacklisted as spam.

And yes, agree with Martin, use third-party API for that - which might be not free after reaching big numbers. But it is reliable. Besides those two, I can recommend [Postmarkapp](https://postmarkapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. One option is to use a service that’s set up to send mass emails, such as [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) or [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/).

Comment: Isn't there any option that doesn't require me to rely on other services I cannot control :/

Comment: @php_nub_qq buy/rent a server and learn to set up and properly manage email services. BUt mailchimp/sendgrid/campaign monitor/etc are cheaper/easier.

Comment: @php_nub_qq The problem is you have to manage *everything*. Reporting, white-listing IPs etc. You would have to build all this from scratch with a self-rolled version, which would cost more than paying the per-campaign cost for Mail Chimp etc and getting all their goodness with that price too.

Comment: @MartinBean I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about.. All I do is fetch all emails from the database and mail() to all of them?

Comment: Today, maybe. But what about in the future when you want to track opens, or click-throughs, or unsubscribes? You’re going to have to write all that functionality yourself.